# check field exits,compare int value using go mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I am using golang as backend with mongodb.I want to perform below code

```
"$match" : bson.M{
        "emp_dept": "xyz",
        "skills":     "asd",
        "emp_del_status": bson.M{"$exists": true, "$eq": 0}, // emp account is active
    }
```

My Collection is

Collection `Employee`

```
{
"emp_dept": "xyz",
"skills":     "fgg",
}
{
"emp_dept": "xyz",
"skills":     "cvv",
}
{
"emp_dept": "xyz",
"skills":     "asd",
"emp_del_status":0,
}
```

In my DB some of the documents do not contain  `emp_del_status` key. So I want to check If any document contains `emp_del_status` key then check the value `0` and return result based on other parameter and `emp_del_status` key both. but if document does not contain `emp_del_status` key then result will come based on other parameters only. How we can check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically what you want is an `$or` for `emp_del_status`.

You want documents where `"emp_dept": "xyz"` **and** `"skills": "asd"`, **and** `emp_del_status` is either `0` **or** missing (does not exist).

This is how you can describe that filter:

```
"$match": bson.M{
    "emp_dept": "xyz",
    "skills":   "asd",
    "$or": []interface{}{
        bson.M{"emp_del_status": bson.M{"$exists": false}},
        bson.M{"emp_del_status": 0},
    },
}
```

Comment: I have re-post the question with collection. Some of Documents do not have `emp_del_status` key.